# Como remover listeners de acordo com estado do componente?

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho um JLabel que recebe um evento, e gostaria de desativar esse evento quando o componente estiver desabilitado (setEnable = false), e só ativá-lo novamente quando o componente estiver habilitado.

o que eu fiz:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NovoClass extends JFrame {

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public NovoClass() {
        setSize(200, 150);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/botãoExcluir.png"));
        JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Enable/Disable");

        imagelabel.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());
        imagelabel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        painel.add(imagelabel);
        imagelabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(painel);
        painel.add(check);

        check.addItemListener((ItemEvent e) -> {
            if (check.isSelected() == true) {
                imagelabel.setEnabled(true);
                imagelabel.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());
            } else {
                imagelabel.setEnabled(false);
                //retirar evento.
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public MouseListener getMouseListener() {

        return new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clicou aqui !");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovoClass novo = new NovoClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o propósito de remover um listener de um componente desativado?

Comment: @Articuno aqui eu não quis estender muito o código, mais o componente em algumas situações, abre JDialogs, ao estar desabilitado, quero evitar que o usuário consiga clicar no label, e abri-los.

Comment: Ainda sim não faz sentido. Acho que você está visualizando pelo lado errado. Ao inves de ficar removendo e readicionando evento no componente, porque não checa se o componente está desativado antes da ação do evento?

Comment: @Articuno mais uma vez que ele esteja habilitado, e ganhe o evento, se for desabilitado depois, o evento vai permanecer lá, ele não vai pede-lo,  sendo assim, mesmo desabilitado, se for clicado ele vai "executar".

Comment: Veja a sugestão do meu ultimo comentário. A abordagem sugerida nele resolve isso. No seu MouseListener, cheque se o componente clicado está ativo, se sim, faça a ação, se nao, nao faça nada.

Comment: @Articuno eu tentei aqui, mais não deu certo, a unica diferença foi na primeira vez, como ele começa desabilitado, ai deu certo a condição. Porém, depois que é habilitado 1 vez, o evento "continua lá"

Comment: Como você está fazendo?

Comment: usando o isEnable eu vejo se o imageLabel ta habiltado, se tiver ele chama o metodo do evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma abordagem mais interessante é filtrar isso direto no listener, ao invés de ficar adicionando e removendo-o conforme algum status do componente.

Para isso, basta recuperar o componente clicado e checar se ele está ativo, se sim, exibe o alerta, se não, não faça nada. Seu exemplo ficaria assim(observe no método `getMouseListener()`):

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class NovoClass extends JFrame {

    private JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public NovoClass() {
        setSize(200, 150);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/botãoExcluir.png"));
        JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);
        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Enable/Disable");

        imagelabel.addMouseListener(getMouseListener());
        imagelabel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        painel.add(imagelabel);
        imagelabel.setEnabled(false);
        add(painel);
        painel.add(check);

        check.addItemListener((ItemEvent e) -> {
            if (check.isSelected() == true) {
                imagelabel.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                imagelabel.setEnabled(false);
                //retirar evento.
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public MouseListener getMouseListener() {

        return new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                JComponent comp = (JComponent) e.getSource();

                if(comp.isEnabled()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clicou aqui !");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(NovoClass::new);
    }
}
```

Provando que funciona realmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]